# How to count all the numbers after word in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="social_service_demo" time="0.583">
  <testsuite name="demo / generate_access_token" id="60ec54b9-d67b-4f51-a20d-9794c3a85269" tests="2" time="0.583">
    <error>
    </error>
    <testcase name="Token should be generated correctly, response is 200" time="0.583">
      <failure type="AssertionFailure">
        <![CDATA[Failed 1 times.]]>
      </failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Returned JSON should contain access_token field" time="0.583">
      <failure type="AssertionFailure">
        <![CDATA[Failed 1 times.]]>
      </failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="demo / get_most_commented_entities" id="12aa656d-a702-4fc6-878c-2e0fde08021e" tests="1" time="0">
    <error>
    </error>
    <testcase name="Response is 200" time="0">
      <failure type="AssertionFailure">
        <![CDATA[Failed 1 times.]]>
      </failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I need to count numbers which are after `tests` word in line like this:
`<testsuite name="demo / generate_access_token" id="60ec5" tests="2" time="0.583">`.
In this example I have two numbers like this: 2 and 1, so my output should be 3. How to do this in Bash? Is it possible with grep?

Comment: You _could_ do something like this: `grep -oE 'tests="[0-9]+"' <my-xml-file> | grep -oE '[0-9]+'` but ... the more feasible solution would be to use an XML parser like libxml to get those specific `<testsuite>` elements

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `grep`, `sed` and alike for parsing XML/HTML data - it'll never come to robust and scalable result. 
Use a proper XML/HTML processors, like **`xmlstarlet`**:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'sum(//testsuite[@tests]/@tests)' -n input.xml
```

The output:

```
3
```

Comment: This needs some other things than `bash` and `grep` to be installed.

Comment: @jiwopene and the reason is mentioned in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU grep (usually pre-installed on linux but not mac) you can use

```
grep -Po 'tests="\K\d*(?=")' inputFile
```

Otherwise you can use

```
grep -Eo 'tests="[0-9]*"' inputFile | grep -Eo '[0-9]*'
```

These commands will print all numbers written in `tests="..."`. To sum up these numbers you could install and use `numsum`:

```
grep ... | numsum
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/tests=/{gsub(/.*=|"/,"",$(NF-1));sum+=$(NF-1)} END{print sum}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o 'tests="[0-9]*"'|grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

This command reads file from stdin writing one number per line to stdout.

Description:

- grep - find utility
- -o - write only matching, not lines
- tests="[0-9]*" - match tests="*anynumber*
- second grep - extract only numbers

You can combine it with `bc` calculator to calculate sum:

```
grep -o 'tests="[0-9]*"'|grep -o '[0-9]*'|paste -sd+|bc
```

If you want to not use `bc` (it is not sometimes installed) and calculate it in pure bash (with use of `grep` and `paste`), you can use `$(($(...)))` notation:

```
echo $(($(grep -o 'tests="[0-9]*"'|grep -o '[0-9]*'|paste -sd+)))
```

If you also do not have `paste`, you can use `while` to replace it:

```
 echo $(($(grep -o 'tests="[0-9]*"'|grep -o '[0-9]*'|while read N; do echo -n "+$N"; done)))
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking the sum of those digits, above will give only digits not sum.